# Error with C# GUI Code

Tags: c#, user-interface, mono

So i was doing a [tutorial on C#](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2013/04/hack-raspberry-pi-how-to-build.html)

for the raspberry pi. They had an image of the C# code but a bit of the image was cut off, so i dont know what goes after it.
Here's the code I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault();
        var f=new Form();
        f.SetBounds(0,0,100,100);
        Application.Run(f);
    }
}
```

I think the problem is on this line:

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault();
```

Because this is the error I get:

test.cs(10,15): error CS1501: No overload for method `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault' takes`0' arguments
/usr/lib/mono/2.0/System.Windows.Forms.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Would someone be able to tell me what is wrong with this code. I am also new to C#.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault(v=vs.110).aspx)

Try

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```